# Button not working on mobile website - wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I can't figure out why this button will not work on mobile. I've tried a few different things but can't seem to get it tow work. Everything is fine on desktop but not on mobile (google inspect or actual iPhone). Using Wordpress.

```js
// Starts the sequence from the GO button
function onSubmit() {
  inputHandler();
  findItem(input)
}
```

```html
<button class="barItem" style="width: 40px" id="submit" onclick={onSubmit()}>GO</button>
```

> **Also Tried this**

```js
// Starts the sequence from the GO button
function onSubmit() {
  inputHandler();
  findItem(input);
}

// Starts the sequence when you press enter
document.getElementById('pNum').onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    onSubmit();
  }
};
```

```html
<input class="barItem" type="submit" onclick={onSubmit()} onsubmit={onSubmit()} value="GO" />
```

Comment: Try using quotes on your onclick `onclick="onSubmit()"` and onsubmit `onsubmit="onSubmit()"`

Comment: Is the `{}` in `onclick={onSubmit()}` a Wordpress syntax?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be onclick="onsubmit()" I believe unless you're using some kind of framework